# Scan entire XML file and grab only nodes needed

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

please ignore the semantics of the XML data. I want to scan the whole xml file and grab only banana values and store them as an array in PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
<fruits>
    <fruit id="1" >
        <aisle1>
            <apple>aa</apple>
            <banana>ab</banana>
            <cherry>ac</cherry>
            <damson>ad</damson>
        </aisle1>
        <aisle2>
            <apple>none</apple>
            <banana>3708650582321691833</banana>
            <cherry>none</cherry>
            <damson>none</damson>
        </aisle2>
        <aisle3>
            <apple>none</apple>
            <banana>3708650582321691833</banana>
            <cherry>none</cherry>
            <damson>none</damson>
        </aisle3>
    </fruit>
    <fruit id="2" >
        <aisle1>
            <apple>none</apple>
            <banana>3708650582321691833</banana>
            <cherry>none</cherry>
            <damson>none</damson>
        </aisle1>
        <aisle2>
            <apple>none</apple>
            <banana>3708650582321691833</banana>
            <cherry>none</cherry>
            <damson>none</damson>
        </aisle2>
        <aisle3>
            <apple>none</apple>
            <banana>3708650582321691833</banana>
            <cherry>none</cherry>
            <damson>none</damson>
        </aisle3>
    </fruit>
</fruits>
```

Can xPath allow me to do this? I currently have:

```
$xml->xpath("//fruits//fruit//bananas->text()";
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes, xpath would be great for this or you could use xquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested on that particular node, just directly query it:

```
$just_bunch_of_bananas = array();
$bananas = $xml->xpath('//banana'); // directly get it
foreach($bananas as $banana) { // loop each banana node :)
    echo $banana . '<br/>';
    $just_bunch_of_bananas[] = (string) $banana;
}
```

By rows:

```
$rows = array();
$fruits = $xml->xpath('//fruit');
foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
    foreach($fruit as $row => $aisles) {
        $rows[] = array('apple' => (string )$aisles->apple, 'banana' => (string )$aisles->banana);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: No way is it that simple... I thought you had to traverse through the data structure, doh!

Comment: What about if I wanted apple and bananas as a group for each?

Comment: @SMKS its a little bit complex, than the previous answer, since every `<aisle>` is different, what i would do it target each fruit instead, i'l draft an answer

Comment: @SMKS that should have been easier given that the names of the aisles are just `<aisles>`, nothing more, instead of numbered aisles